# How to get all processing and pending orders programmatically?

Tags: magento2, orders, programmatically

How can I get a list of all the orders in processing and pending status in Magento 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should use Service Contracts Layer:

```
class OrderCollectData
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $orderRepository;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder
     */
    protected $filterBuilder;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
        ->addFilter(
           'status',
           'processing',
           'eq'
        )
        ->addFilter(
           'status',
           'pending',
           'eq'
        )->create();

        $orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
        foreach ($orders->getItems() as $order) {
               //Your code
        };

        // Using filterBuilder
        $statusProcessingFilter = $this->filterBuilder
           ->setField('status')
           ->setConditionType('eq')
           ->setValue('processing')
           ->create();
        $statusPendingFilter = $this->filterBuilder
           ->setField('status')
           ->setConditionType('eq')
           ->setValue('pending')
           ->create();

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
           ->addFilters([$statusProcessingFilter, $statusPendingFilter])
           ->create();

        $orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

        foreach ($orders as $order) {
           // Process each order as needed
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```php
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
) {
    $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
}

public function getOrderCollection($status)
{
    $orderCollection = $this->orderCollectionFactory
        ->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['eq'=> $status]);

    return $orderCollection;
}
```

So you would call

```
$this->getOrderCollection('processing')
$this->getOrderCollection('pending')
```